# How to upload file with BackgroundTransfer for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

have check the documentation but there is no sample to show how this is done. This is the code for download :

```
void Download()
{
    btr = new BackgroundTransferRequest(remoteVideoUri, localDownloadUri);
    btr.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;
    BackgroundTransferService.Add(btr);
    btr.TransferProgressChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(btr_TransferProgressChanged);
    btr.TransferStatusChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(btr_TransferStatusChanged);
}
```

For upload, can it be done with this backgroudTransfer ?  what and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't yet had chance to look at the background transfer stuff in Mango yet, but there is a lab that covers it in the Mango Offline Training Kit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WP7MangoTrainingCourse and I do know that it can do uploads as well as downloads.